# Choosing the sign of determinant when taking a square root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Calculate the determinant $$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c&d\\ \:\:\:-b&a&d&-c\\ \:\:\:-c&-d&a&b\\ \:\:\:-d&c&-b&a\end{vmatrix}$$

I found that $$\det(A)\det(A^T)=\det(A)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^4$$
From this we get
$$\det(A) = \pm (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$$
Now, how to choose the sign? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations  your matrix is pretty similar to the first one, you just need to negate your $b,c,d$

Comment: @WillJagy - Yes, that is the transpose of this matrix. Yet, I didn't notice if they provided the way of calculation... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one quick way: Use the standard cofactor formula for the determinant. Expand only what you need. What is the sign of $a^4$?

Answer (score 6):

Evaluate it at $A=I$ gives you the sign.

Comment: Sorry, but why is this?

Comment: @VIVID In the case $a=1$, $b,c,d=0$ we have $A=I_4$ and hence it's determinant is just $1$ which gives you the sign.

Comment: @PeterForeman - I'm pretty sure the question was "why should every matrix $A$ have the same sign choice?", not "how do you apply the formula to $A = I$ to get the sign?".

Comment: @PaulSinclair This is because if a polynomial is zero, the polynomial *function* it induces must also be zero.

Comment: While I was not asking for myself at all, understanding very well why it is true, (for real matrices, there is a simple continuity argument, for example), your explanation sheds absolutely no light on the matter at all that I can see. Indeed, it begs the question of what "induced polynomial function" are you referring to? How is this induced function different from the polynomial itself?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, I didn't notice your message until now. The polynomial function induced by a polynomial refers to the function whose value is obtained by replacing the indeterminates of the polynomial by the values of the function arguments (on some function domain). I think the difference between polynomial and polynomial function has been taught in many introductory algebra courses. E.g. $x$ and $x^3+x^2+x$ are two different polynomials, but $a\mapsto a$ and $a\mapsto a^3+a^2+a$ are the same function on $GF(2)$.

Comment: ... Two different polynomials can induce the same polynomial function, but when two polynomials induce two different polynomial functions, the two polynomials must be different. In our case, $f(x,y,z,w)=\det(A(x,y,z,w))$ and $g(x,y,z,w=-(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)^2$ are different functions on $\mathbb R^4$, because $f(1,0,0,1)=1\ne4=g(1,0,0,1)$. Therefore $\det(A(a,b,c,d))$ and $-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$ (where $a,b,c,d$ are indeterminates) cannot be the same polynomial. Since $\det(A(a,b,c,d))$ must be equal to either $-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$ or $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$, the latter one must be correct.